# Парсер новых товаров

Tags: php, mysql, парсер, curl, cron

Приведу полный пример.
Рассмотрим доску объявлений. Я хочу первый узнать о каком-либо товаре. Мне, к примеру, нужен acer aspire 5742g. Я выбираю ЦП, объем ОП, видюху и ценник. Как только появляется товар который подходит по моим фильтрам мне приходит смс. Т.е. объявления, которые были выложены ранее, мне не интересны. Таких фильтров может быть 50. 
Алгоритм такой:

1. Бери фильтр, забирай страницу курлом.
2. Собирай ИД товаров .
3. Сравнивай их с уже имеющимися в БД.
4. Если есть ИД которого нет в базе - отправляй СМС и добавляй его в бд.
5. Иначе ничего не делай.

Проблема в том, что как только появляется N пользователей (для примера возьмем 100) и у каждого по 50 фильтров, то к этой доске объявлений по крону, каждую минуту, будет улетать по 5000 запросов (а если взять 1000 пользователей, то это вообще 50к =_=). От этого не избавишься, только если искать среди всех одинаковые фильтра и делать всего один запрос. Но это будут крупицы.

Ну и естественно сервер доски объявлений будет не рад такой активности... Купить Проксей? А сколько? Грубо говоря по 1-ой на юзера? Только такое решение? 
Буду рад послушать ваши мысли на этот счет!

Comment: Ваш вопрос не подходит для сайта so. С натяжкой разве что в "алгоритмы". И вообще за такое я бил бы по рукам. Так что вопрос, скорее всего, заминусуют.

Но раз я сам делал такое....

Количество проксей считается исходя из идеи "какая пауза должна быть между запросами через одну проксю/сколько запросов за период должно идти через проксю + резерв". По факту сделать из них очередь и перебирать ее циклически.

И парсить нужно не фильтры, а разделы, которых всяко меньше. При обновлении информации сверять с нужными фильтрами и уведомлять.

Comment: Также есть смысл проверять время модификации страницы запросом Head или же работать с парой Last-Modified и If-Modified-Since, чтобы минимизировать трафик.

Еще можно высчитать время обновления раздела и предсказать время следующего запроса, а не долбить каждую минуту (но это уже от конечного сайта зависит)

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Спасибо за ответ! Т.е. вы предлагаете парсить все разделы к себе в бд, а потом уже по ней осуществлять поиск? Да, не плохо, от кол-ва юзеров кол-во запросов будет не изменным!
Долбить нужно в любом случае каждую минуту, т.к. хочется первым просмотреть объявление. Если бы на страницах не было рекламы и различного динамического контента, я бы просто смотрел по content-length и всё )
А вот про ваши заголовки я не подумал, пойду смотреть ) Спасибо, что не поленились ответить!

Comment: Нет. "осуществлять поиск" - значит что хоть вы меньше будете долбить доску объявлений, но юзеры будут по прежнему долбить ваш сервер. Лучше сохранять фильтры как подписки и не "поиск по базе", а "новые данные при появлении проверяют себя не подходят ли они под какие фильтры и если да, то уведомляют подписчика" - так минимизируется долбежка "сервиса нотификатора"

Comment: Если же пользователям предоставляется не чистый сервер "который следит за другой доской", а чистое зеркало - то тут либо тащить к себе весь сайт (что неразумно), либо проксировать запросы к доске попутно обновляя у себя данные (неудобно в реализации ибо прокси будут тупить и все будет тормозить). Передо мной задача юзер-френдли не стояла - я выбирал нужный фильтр на конечном сайте и сохранял его как подписку в моем "нотификаторе"

Comment: У меня был личный проект и мне хватало просто вбить урл с фильтром и долбить его каждую минуту. Потом ip заблокировали и пришлось мудрить с прокси. У вас же 100 фильтров это 100 запросов в  минуту, но если они к 1-2 разделам на самом деле, то можно делать 1-2 запроса без фильтров и потом уже на лету применять фильтры.

Comment: Спасибо за еще один совет, будет над чем подумать )
Эхх ... было бы 1-2 раздела, но по факту мы имеем 930 и в каждым разделе свои товары :))